# What is the English word for the empty space in a question in an exercise like: "Fill the ___ with..."?

Tags: word-request

In many books and sites of English learners there are exercise that require from the learner to put the missing word / article in the 'space' between two words or at the end of the sentence.

What is this place called? ("Fill the ___ with the correct articles in following sentence") For now I didn't find the term in English or in my language.

Comment: What did you look for when you couldn't find a suitable term in either English or or native language?

Comment: @ColleenV, I commented here the right answer. But I can't find it now. Is there any rule here in ELL that, peoples here with high reputation can delete others comments if they want to.

Comment: @ColleenV I didn't look for something because I didn't have what to look for, since I didn't know the term either in my language or in English.

Comment: So, you didn't consider looking up ["space"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/space) at all? Some example definitions: "a blank area separating words or lines", "an empty area between things".  It seems strange that the English exercises you've been working on don't have instructions in your language or in English.

Comment: Maybe it seemsstrangebutit is true. I didn't remember the name from then. I live in other country today.

Answer (score 4):

The space is called a "blank" or just a "space".

> Fill the blanks with the correct article....

This type of exercise is called a cloze exercise.  Note the spelling. It comes from the "Law of closure" in Gestalt theory: That we perceive of objects (for example sentences) as whole, even when parts are missing.